# ccnet - how to read version info from AssemblyInfo.cs and use as ccnet version label

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, assemblyinfo

I have .net project with pre-filled AssamblyVersion in Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs file. I looking for some way how pass this parameter back to CCNET, to version label or to CCNetLabel parameter (its probably same thing).

Exist there some simple way with some external labeller or by some NAnt, powershell... script?

Comment: Usually you'll have the build script generate the AssemblyInfo.cs file using the build property that is passed in from cruise control.

Comment: Unfortunately in this case is Version filled by developer and is incremented manually.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that. That isn't what you would want to do when using cruise control .net though, you want the version to get automatically incremented using the build label and optionally the VCS revision number.

Comment: I am aware of this :)

Comment: My "in general" advice about CC.NET is to treat it as a "super fancy msbuild.exe caller" and put most of your logic/tasks inside a .proj (msbuild definition) file.  And use the built-in cc.net tasks as sparingly as possible (like "Get Source Code").    Then messing with the version number becomes more trivial.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. We tried this approach before and IMHO its also right way. But I just trying move this task from msbuild into more simple ccnet configuration and general simplify overall configuration for new projects.

Comment: If you ever move to TFS, you'll regret that decision.  Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for this note. TFS server is primary based on msbuild configurations?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found this solution

http://predicatet.blogspot.cz/2007/10/version-custom-cruisecontrolnet.html

This is custom labeller for CCNET.